# Can't Source Shared Library/Resources for Bryntum Scheduler in React Project When Calling Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, bryntum-scheduler

Ok, so I'm working with the Bryntum Scheduler trial version 3.1.1. I created a new react project folder and ran the installer to pull the Bryntum stuff into the project. I also copied the Bryntum shared resources into the main project folder (not the folder of the individual project) (folder: **_shared_b**). I also copied the "simple" example project source files into my new project. I also ran the build onto the shared resources located under the examples folder (the copy in my main project structure is also built) (folder: **_shared_a**). And I copied the build folder from the main trial folder into the project top level (folder: **_build**). So, I have a structure like this:

```
+ Projects
-- _build
-- _shared_a
-- _shared_b
-- react_scheduler
```

In my package.json in the dependencies I have the following to refer to these folders:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
  "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
  "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
  "bryntum-react-shared": "file:../../_shared_a/build",
  "bryntum-resources": "file:../../_shared_b",
  "bryntum-scheduler": "file:../../_build",
  "react": "^16.13.1",
  "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
  "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
}
```

And here's my webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    output: {
        filename: "scheduler.js",
        path: __dirname + "/dist"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        cacheDirectory: true,
                        babelrc: false,
                        presets: [
                            "@babel/env",
                            "@babel/react"
                        ],
                        plugins: [
                            "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: {
                    loader: "html-loader"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/i,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ttf|woff|woff2|eot)$/i,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
                use: [
                    // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
                        'style-loader',
                    // Translates CSS into CommonJS
                        'css-loader',
                    // Compiles Sass to CSS
                        'sass-loader'
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

For comparison the path references by default in the "simple" example looks like this:

```
"bryntum-react-shared": "file:../../_shared/build",
"bryntum-resources": "file:../../../_shared",
"bryntum-scheduler": "file:../../../../build",
```

The source project has the following path:

**\scheduler-3.1.1-trial\examples\react\javascript\simple**

The original _shared_a has the following path:

**\scheduler-3.1.1-trial\examples\react_shared**

The original _shared_b has this path:

**\scheduler-3.1.1-trial\examples_shared**

And the original _build has this path:

**\scheduler-3.1.1-trial\build**

However, when I run webpack (using **npx webpack --mode production**) to have the whole thing built and packaged, I get these errors:

```
ERROR in ./src/components/Header.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'bryntum-react-shared' in 'C:\Projects\react-scheduler\src\components'
 @ ./src/components/Header.js 23:0-78 51:47-52 54:39-52 60:39-52 67:39-52 76:39-55
 @ ./src/containers/Main.js
 @ ./src/App.js
 @ ./src/index.js

ERROR in ./src/containers/Main.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'bryntum-react-shared' in 'C:\Projects\react-scheduler\src\containers'
 @ ./src/containers/Main.js 26:0-56 122:43-59
 @ ./src/App.js
 @ ./src/index.js

ERROR in ./src/App.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'bryntum-react-shared/resources/shared.scss' in 'C:\Projects\react-scheduler\src'
 @ ./src/App.js 8:0-52
 @ ./src/index.js
```

So, what is it I'm missing?

Comment: Did you create your app with [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/) scripts? I see that you install them in `package.json` yet you use a custom webpack config. Or, did you eject?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to generate React app with [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/). There is a video guide showing the whole process in [Bryntum React Integration Guide](https://bryntum.com/docs/scheduler/#guides/integration/react.md).

The minimum files for the empty Scheduler to appear in the browser are:

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { BryntumScheduler } from 'bryntum-react-shared';

function App() {
  return (
    <BryntumScheduler />
  );
}

export default App;
```

and App.css:

```
@import "~bryntum-scheduler/scheduler.stockholm.css"
```

If you cannot or do not want to use CRA scripts, you can run `npm run eject` in `bryntum-demo` directory afterwards. The workable `webpack.config.js` is to be found in `config` directory created by eject.

Then you can either add what you need into it or you can merge it with your `webpack.config.js`.

Note: I've created many React apps with CRA and so far I haven't found the reason why should I eject or use a custom Webpack configuration. Maybe you can go with CRA as well.